# Write item to DynamoDB using Apache Camel with Java Annotations for DynamoDB

Tags: java, apache-camel, amazon-dynamodb

**Situation**

I am trying to write to DynamoDB using the [Apache Camel aws2-ddb component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/aws2-ddb-component.html). My route reads from a relational database using JPA, performs a transformation to the target class and puts that class into a DynamoDB table.

The target class looks like this (more complex in reality, of course)

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "MyDataTable")
public class MyData {
    private String key;
    private String foo;
    private List<String> bar;

    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "key")
    public String getKey() { return key; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "foo")
    public String getFoo() { return foo; }

    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "bar")
    public List<String> getBar() {  return bar; }

    // ...
}
```

Using only the AWS SDK I would simply do something like this:

```
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
mapper.save(myDataItem);
```

The aws2-ddb component however requires the item as a `Map<String, AttributeValue>`.

**Question**

How can I transform the annotated class to `Map<String, AttributeValue>`? It feels like this should be something obvious but I seem to be unable to find anything in the AWS SDK.

(As I workaround I could implement the above `DynamoDBMapper` code in a custom processor, but I'd prefer to use the component.)

Answer (score 0):

Unofunetelly during the *camel-aws-ddb* lib drill down, I found no possibility to use DynamoDbMapper.
Basically, the *aws-dbb*/*aws2-dbb* components use DdbProducer under the hood which in fact is a Processor calling a *ddbClient* putItem in your case.

The possible options are:

- Writing your own component using of *DynamoDBMapper* instead of pure *ddbClient*.
- A custom processor as you've mentioned above by setting an item in the header (or even bean if you don't have to deal with the message itself).
- Just using the current API which allows the use of items of type
  **List<Map<String, AttributeValue>>** putting them in the message header in the end.